# How to Clear Activity Stack without New Intent

Tags: android, twitter4j

Let me clear the question with details. I'm using `twitter4j` in my application. It's working well and you know `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` is calling back to `onNewIntent` method in Activity.

I'm satisfying the callback like this:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Twitter callback -> New Intent");
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this,consumer, provider, prefs). execute(uri);
    }
}
```

Everything is okay until I press the back button. When I pressed the activity returns web page which contains authorizing page.

Is there any way to clear Activity stack onNewIntent? I don't want to call same Intent as a restart and not sure any different way out.

**Update**: I'm calling the auth page like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
```

Can you give any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't included the code for opening the auth page in the browser. What flags are you setting when calling the browser view? I think that is where you problem lies.

Are you using something like...

```
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(token.getAuthorizationURL()));
webIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Comment: Updated my answer, what's wrong with that flag? Thank you btw.

Comment: I think the problem could be the other flags being set. You want to create a new intent rather than using a browser which is already running in the background. Try removing SINGLE_TOP and FROM_BACKGROUND. You can then add them back in one at a time to identify which one is causing the issue.